# Can I freeze unbaked scones?

Tags: baking, freezing

Well, the title says it all really! Can I freeze unbaked scones, or am I better off baking them and then freezing to reheat? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend freezing them unbaked. The crumb is a lot more delicate once they're baked and more susceptible to moisture migration, leading to them being soggy or stale (or both! at the same time!) when thawed. Scones, being relatively low moisture and not containing yeast, actually freeze quite well and can usually go straight from the freezer to the oven.

I've worked in several bakeries where we made giant batches of one flavor of scone and froze dough all portioned out so that we could always have several flavors of freshly baked.

Comment: Thank you. How long do you think a batch of unbaked scones would last in a domestic freezer?

Comment: @Fiona If your freezer stays consistently below freezing and they're wrapped airtight, probably 6 months to a year? There isn't really much that can happen to them.

Comment: Yeah, I used to make 1200 scones a week in a professional bakery, and most would be frozen raw until needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're most definitely better off baking them and then freezing them.  Breads and pastries freeze beautifully.  I worked at a Starbucks and we received all of our pastries frozen because of our location being outside of the main distribution area.  It didn't make a difference from the ones we received unfrozen at another store.  Just don't defrost them and freeze them again!